# Can't iptables-restore due to FATAL: Module ip_tables not found

Tags: centos

this is very puzzling.

Centos 6.4 on a VPS.

iptables -L works, and I can enter rules and delete rules as needed using the iptables command.
I can even see the saved rules in sysconfig/ and they are correct.

HOWEVER, iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.firewall.rules always fails with:

```
FATAL: Module ip_tables not found.
'ptables-restore v1.4.7: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter

Error occurred at line: 1
```

My rules are as follow (verbatim). They are a copy of what linode recommends in their tutorial.

```
*filter

#  Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

#  Accept all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#  Allow all outbound traffic - you can modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

#  Allow HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites and SSL).
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

#  Allow SSH connections but block (slow) brute force attempts
#  The -dport number should be the same port number you set in sshd_config
#
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 10 -j DROP

#  Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

#  Drop all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP

COMMIT
```

Comment: You sat those rules are verbatim, but is there any possibility that a spurious ^M has crept in at the end of each line?  It would explain the odd carriage return you're seeing just before the last single-quote of the error message.  Try `vi -b /etc/sysconfig/iptables` (I assume that's the file you quote above) to look for non-printing characters at the end of lines.

Comment: MadHatter, color me impressed, you're correct!!!! Now question is, how did they get there? I use the same editor (sublime) for everything.

Comment: I've written my comment up as an answer, in case you want to accept it (it would be best practice to accept *an* answer to this question, otherwise it'll keep floating back up the list of questions until the end of days).

Comment: Will mark it as answered as soon as I got a chance to try it out tonight :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the single-quote that ought to follow the word `filter` has migrated itself back to the start of the line makes me very suspicious that the rules file contains spurious `^M` characters at the ends of lines, and that `iptables` is actually complaining that it `can't initialise table 'filter^M'` - which it most certainly can't, there being no such table.

This non-printing (and thus hard to see) `^M` would have come from the first line of the file you quote above, if it was in fact `*filter^M`.

The easiest way to be sure is to open the file with `vi` in binary mode, `vi -b /etc/sysconfig/iptables` (I'm assuming that's the file you're quoting above), and look for non-printing characters that shouldn't be there.

How such characters might have got there I couldn't say for sure, but I often find that the baleful presence of a Windows box in the vicinity correlates with the appearance of spurious carriage-returns.

**Edit**: since that seems to have been the problem, may I make one small, pontificating recommendation for "things one can learn from this episode"?  Which is: that the detailed anomalies are important when debugging free software.

Commercial software does things for non-technical reasons, so quite often nothing can be inferred from apparent anomalies.  But free software tends not to do that; if, say, a single-quote has appeared at the beginning of a line where it normally doesn't, there's usually a technical reason for it - and that can be of great help in debugging.

Comment: bingo. Thank you very much for your detailled answer.